# SSRS XML export - removing the BOM

Tags: xml, reporting-services, byte-order-mark

I use SSRS to generate an XML file using XSLT.  All is fine, except that the XML file starts with the letters 'EF BB BF' which I need to get rid of.  How do I generate an XML file without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-encoding the entire XML, thus removing the BOMs.